# http to https redirect with Apache2 is not working

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I am currently working on a AWS instance hosting a website using Apache. I have setup my SSL, I can go to the https://example.com just fine, but when I go to http://example.com I don't get redirected. With that I have tried the following:

- in my example.com.conf I have tried Redirect permenant / https blah blah
- also in .conf have used many rewrite rules all claiming 'this will work with any config'. I have enable Apache2 rewrite mod also.
- I have run `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf`

Here is my .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ... all my site stuff
</IfModule>
```

I will be so grateful to anyone who can help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` => change all`AllowOverride` all,

and make sure that `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000.default.conf` => verify the path of the Directory that you access.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/floder that you acess /public
<Directory /var/www/ninja/public>   
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/420272/apache-redirect-from-http-to-https-not-working